# How to make MouseHookProc don't process the click

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to use SetWindowsHookExA() with WH_MOUSE_LL to ready low level mouse clicks that are injected.

Here is my code for hooking.

```
DWORD dwThreadMain; // The process main thread. (Already have this)
HWND mainWindow; // Already have this pointer
MSG hMsg;

MouseHOOK = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProc, NULL, dwThreadMain);
if (!MouseHOOK) {
    // Cant't Hook
}

KeyBoardHOOK = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyBoardHookProc, NULL, dwThreadMain);
if (!KeyBoardHOOK) {
    // Cant't HOOK
}

while (GetMessage(&hMsg, mainWindow, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&hMsg);
    DispatchMessage(&hMsg);
}
```

This is my MouseHookProc and KeyBoardHookProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        if (wParam == WM_RBUTTONUP || wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN
            || wParam == WM_LBUTTONUP || wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

            if ((hookStruct->flags & LLMHF_INJECTED) == LLMHF_INJECTED) {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "MOUSE INJECTED!", "POOR MOUSE", MB_OK);
                return TRUE;
            }

            if ((hookStruct->flags & LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED) == LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED) {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "MOUSE INJECTED!", "POOR MOUSE", MB_OK);
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(MouseHOOK, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyBoardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* hookStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

            if ((hookStruct->flags & LLKHF_INJECTED) == LLKHF_INJECTED) {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "KEYBOARD INJECTED!", "POOR KEYBOARD", MB_OK);
                return TRUE;
            }

            if ((hookStruct->flags & LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED) == LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED) {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "KEYBOARD INJECTED!", "POOR KEYBOARD", MB_OK);
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(KeyBoardHOOK, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The problem here is not on hooking, the message boxes are showing when the injected flag is there. The KeyBoard blocks the input. But only in mouse, the 'return TRUE' don't prevent the click to be processed.

I Think I've missed something... There is another way to do this?

Comment: You must remove the MessageBox() calls to get ahead, not clicking the OK button fast enough will trip a timeout.  Consider OutputDebugString() instead.

Comment: The message box was only to see if it's hooking. even without it, the click don1t stop the click.

Comment: On a side note, your message loop is filtering ALL messages by `HWND`. [Don't do that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493). You need to preform an unfiltered retrieval once in awhile so internal system messages can be processed, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If I understand you... changing that while to this ```while (GetMessage(&hMsg, NULL, 0, 0))``` should help... inside should get window that click and do the trick, right?

Comment: @Carlos yes, pass a NULL HWND to GetMessage(). I have no idea if that will fix your problem, but it is something you need to do regardless.

Comment: you can not modify or drop message inside HookProc, but you can set some flag (*process* or *skip*) in thread tls and after call `GetMessage` check this flag in tls. if *skip* not call `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage`